# Route localhost_access_log in tomcat to console

Tags: tomcat

How can we route the localhost_access_log present in /logs folder to console for tomcat?

Is there any configuration value which can route this to console in server.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                       prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```